# Cancel to retain previous state is not working

Tags: reactjs, state, reset

I have apply and cancel button with list of checkeboxes.
Once apply is clicked the selected/checked value should get stored in state `prevVal` variable.
On seleting some other check box and clicking cancel should make checkbox to get populated with `prevVal`

But on clicking cancel `currentValue` is getting populated.

I am using a temporary variable to hold the current state on handle checkbox event.

After I push value to a temporary variable my state is getting auto updated with the temporary value.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Please find the slackblits link below 
(https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ud1mtm)

Comment: Sivalakshmi, let me know what you think. I just wrote an answer for you below. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what youre looking for :)
Also here is the sandbox if you want to see the functionality: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pmdgir?file=index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      prevVal: [],
      currentVal: [],
      filter: [
        {
          key: 'a'
        },
        {
          key: 'b'
        },
        {
          key: 'c'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  toggleCurrentVal = (key) => {
    const currentVal = this.state.currentVal
    const beforeSlicedVal = []

    if(currentVal.includes(key)){
      currentVal.splice(currentVal.indexOf(key), 1)
    } else {
      currentVal.push(key)
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const prevStateValue = prevState.prevVal.length <= currentVal.length ? prevState.currentVal.filter((val) => val !== key) : prevState.prevVal
      return {
         currentVal: currentVal.sort(),
         prevVal: prevStateValue
      }
    }, () => console.log("currentValue:"+ this.state.currentVal + " preValue: " + this.state.prevVal ))
  }

  applyFilter = () => {
      console.log("currentValue:"+ this.state.currentVal + " preValue: " + this.state.prevVal )
  }

  cancel = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentVal: [],
      prevVal: this.state.currentVal
    }, () => console.log("currentValue:"+ this.state.currentVal + " preValue: " + this.state.prevVal ))
  }

  render() {
    let checkboxes = [];
    let checkedValues = this.state.currentVal
    if (this.state.filter) {
      this.state.filter.map(data => {
        checkboxes.push(
          <div><input type="checkbox" checked={checkedValues.includes(data.key)}name="a" value={data.key} onClick={() => this.toggleCurrentVal(data.key)}></input></div>
        )
      })
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {checkboxes}
        <button onClick={this.applyFilter}>Apply</button>
        <button onClick={this.cancel}>Cancel</button>
      </div>)
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks Christopher, But i am expecting like below

Current Val:[a,b] //items checked in screen
Prev Val:[a] //value once apply is clicked - even if again checkboxes are ticked unless giving apply this should remain same

Comment: Ah okay, Let me know if the updated works. With this, you shouldnt even have to worry about apply.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution.. The term which i am trying is shallow and deep copy in react js( just now got the those buzzwords).  I am using another button to reset the content in where update is working fine. Thank you